# Find the maximum and minimum values absolute value

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So I am asked to find the maximum and minimum  of the function:

$$f(x)=(2+|x|)\sqrt{2+(2-x)^2}$$ on the interval $[-1,2]$

So I took the derivative and got:

$$\frac{ 2((x-2)|x|+x(x^2-3x+3)) }{|x|\sqrt{(2+(2-x)^2}}$$

which is in fact correct. So I set it equal to zero and try to find the critical points.

The problem is though, how do I solve for $2((x-2)|x|+x(x^2-3x+3))=0$??? I certainly can't see a way...

Comment: $|x|=\begin{cases} x\quad \text{if}\quad x\geq 0\\-x\quad \text{if}\quad x<0\end{cases}$

Comment: Beware: Numerator and denominator are both zero for $x=0$

Comment: Yep! I got 0 as one of them. Another solution is 1 though. How would I solve for that? :/ .

Comment: Why is $f$ differentiable? I can't see why it should be at $0$.

Comment: Because it's also where the denominator is undefined. So the denominator is undefined when x=0 hence it is also a critical point.

Comment: @SubhashisChakraborty. While not a proof, it doesn't hurt to graph the function. It can be very helpful

Comment: It is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: It's okay, I got it!

Comment: Yes but it is undefined at that point so it is still a critical point!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f$ is positive on the entire domain of consideration.

Note that $f$ is non increasing on $[-1,0]$ since it is the product of two
non increasing, non negative functions. Hence we need only consider the points
$\{-1,0\}$ in the context of $x \in [-1,0]$.

For $x\ge 0$, we have
$f(x) = (x+2)\sqrt{x^2-4x+6}$, and $f'(x) = 2{(x-1)^2 \over \sqrt{x^2-4x+6} }$.
In particular, $f'(x) \ge 0$ for $x \in [0,2]$. Hence we need only consider
the points $\{0,2\}$.

Since $f$ is non increasing on $[-1,0]$ and increasing on $[0,2]$, the
maximum value must occur at either $\{-1,2\}$, evaluating shows that the maximum occurs at $f(-1) = 3 \sqrt{11}$. Similarly, the minimum must occur
at $f(0) = 2 \sqrt{6}$.